# Angularjs dateRangePicker - next and previous buttons not working on mobile devices

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, daterangepicker

I'm using Angular date range picker in my Ionic app. The problem that I'm now facing is that on mobile view in a browser, or even on a mobile device, the 'next' and 'previous' buttons not working.

Please help me, feeling really very helpless. Thanks in advance.

```
`$scope.datePicker = {date: {startDate: null, endDate: null}};
$('#customeDateRange').daterangepicker({
    "opens": "left",
    "linkedCalendars": false
  },
  function(startDate, endDate, label) {
      console.log(startDate, endDate)
      console.log(moment(startDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD'))
      $scope.StartDate = moment(startDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
      $scope.EndDate = moment(endDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
      getInsuranceWiseClaimCount();
  });`
```

Comment: please help me don't ignore i'll change sample code if u want more but please help me

Answer (score 0):

Change in daterangepicker.js file for Ionic
Add One more line for touch handling

For prev button

```
.on('click.daterangepicker', '.prev', $.proxy(this.clickPrev, this))
.on('touchstart.daterangepicker', '.prev', $.proxy(this.clickPrev, this))
```

For Next

```
.on('click.daterangepicker', '.next', $.proxy(this.clickPrev, this))
.on('touchstart.daterangepicker', '.next', $.proxy(this.clickPrev, this))
```